# Как написать условие rewrite в nginx

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx, redirect, rewrite

Есть урлы вида **test.ru/location#/auth/login** без слэша после location, нужно сделать rewrite со слэшем вначале, например **test.ru/location/#/auth/login**

Пример моего конфига

```
location ^~ /location {
    rewrite ^([^/])(.*)$ /location/$1$2 permanent;
    proxy_pass         http://api:3000/location;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: Можно вообще без rewrite. См http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location в конце

Answer (score 1):

Все решил, нужно было заменить на `rewrite ^(/location)$ $1/ permanent;`